# Is the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error message from the browser or from XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

When doing a (intentional failing) cross-domain-request with the following code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
request.onerror = function(error) {
    alert(error.target.status)
};
request.send()
```

I will get the following expected error message in the developer console.:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

**But is this error message from the XmlHttpRequest or from the Browser?**

I want to graps that error message from the XmlHttpRequest, but I can't see where.

With the above code I would expect (as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16931075/343475) to see an error message in the alert box, but all I get is `0`.

Comment: You're trying to load a page from a domain different from yours, and the browser is telling you that because that domain doesn't respond with an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header it will not perform the HTTP request. So, it's the browser telling you "NO".

Comment: @Pointy you missed the point of the question. OP is not asking what the error is. OP is asking where it is generated from so he can get the correct error message.

Comment: just saw this: according to answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5022962/343475 ,it is the browser and the error can't be catched by javascript.

Comment: @epascarello no I understood that, and I thought I answered it in that I said the message was coming from the browser.

Comment: The `XmlHttpRequest` class is part of the browser, so there is no point in distinguishing between them.

Comment: @Quentin I think the OP was asking essentially whether the error could be handled as a request error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is this error message from the XmlHttpRequest or from the Browser?

XMLHttpRequest is part of the browser. So "yes".

If you meant "Is the error from the server or from the browser" then it is from the browser. The server can't know if you are making a cross origin request or not.

> With the above code I would expect (as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16931075/343475) to see an error message in the alert box, but all I get is 0.

The status code would provide information about the resource on the foreign origin (it would tell you if the resource existed and if the user of the browser had permission to access it) so it is suppressed by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: 'The server can't know if you are making a cross origin request' made it clear, and makes much sense if you think about.