# XDomainRequest - Get response body on error

Tags: cors, xdomainrequest

I'm having trouble with XDomainRequest `onerror` handler. When error occurs, I don't seem to be able to get the body of HTTP response (through `xdr.responseText`). Successful requests (200 OK) work fine.

Here is the request:

```
POST http://localhost/path HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
Accept-Language: cs-CZ
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 34
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

[Data]
```

And here is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 54
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 30 Apr 2012 20:57:32 GMT

[Data]
```

Is it possible to obtain the response body?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it is not possible to get the response body on error. All you can know is that an error has occurred. See my related question here: [Is it possible to trap CORS errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors)

One possible workaround (if you have control over the server) is to always return HTTP 200, but include the error code in the body of the response.

Comment: How is it possible that it works in Chrome (which is using XmlHttpRequest)? Is it only limitation of XDomainRequest or is Chrome implementation wrong?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have access to a Windows box at the moment, but I can verify that Chrome does indeed return the body. Note that IE's XDomainRequest is a different object than Chrome's XmlHttpRequest (Level 2), so they don't have to agree on behavior. IE10 will support XmlHttpRequest and CORS.

Comment: Firefox works the same as Chrome. I can still get response even in case of error.