# XDomainRequest not working in IE9

Tags: get, xmlhttprequest, httpwebrequest, xdomainrequest

i'm trying to load a XML document that is not in the web application folder but on level up through a GET request. the loadXMLDoc works fine for FF and chrome but the XDR doesn't for IE.

i'm calling the method like this:

```
xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("../XML/stops_group1.xml");
```

I'm lead to believe the problem lies in going up one level in the root directory, because it works fine for same directory folders

```
function loadXMLDoc(url) {

    if (typeof XDomainRequest != 'undefined') {

        var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
        xdr.contentType = "text/plain";
        xdr.timeout = 5000;
        if (xdr) {
            xdr.onerror = function () {
                alert('XDR onerror');
                alert("Got: " + xdr.responseText);
            };
            xdr.ontimeout = function () {
                alert('XDR ontimeout');
                alert("Got: " + xdr.responseText);
            };
            xdr.onprogress = function () {
                alert("XDR onprogress");
                alert("Got: " + xdr.responseText);
            };
            xdr.onload = function () {
                alert('onload' + xdr.responseText);
                callback(xdr.responseText);
            };
            // 2. Open connection with server using GET method
            xdr.open("get", url);
            // 3. Send string data to server
            xdr.send("");
        } else {
            alert('failed to create xdr');
        }
        return xdr.responseXML;
    }
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
    if (!xhr) {
        throw new Error('CORS not supported');
    }

    xhr.send("");
    return xhr.responseXML;
}

function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
        // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

I already tried adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

but still get the alert message for onError with responseText empty...

Any clues?

Comment: Can you try the full url (with "http://..." etc) rather than the "../"? Here is a list of all the restrictions on XDomainRequest; does your request meet any of the other criteria: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: Also regarding empty text in onError, this seems to be by design: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies... actually my problem was other... seems that IE can't handle the UTF-16 encoding present in the xml file... changed to utf-8 and evertything is well now