# How to obtain the error message in XDomainRequest object?

Tags: javascript, onerror, xdomainrequest

I see my method for error handling invoked **but** since there's no arguments in, I don't know how to check **what** kind of error it is.

```
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.onerror = function(e){
  alert(e);
}
```

In the above example `e` is *undefined*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing CORS, the error message is not available. And *XDomainRequest* **is** by the very definition of it *cross-origin*.

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors) as well as [this definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#handling-a-response-to-a-cross-origin-request).

Comment: Not true, even in the links: "This does not include HTTP responses that indicate some type of error, such as HTTP status code 410."

Comment: @Dtipson Care to provide a minimal example so we can verify? I'll gladly stand corrected if you get anything useful in the response because it's always been a pain to figure out what the error is.