# Postman Resolving "Invalid CORS request" for a POST Request

Tags: api, rest, postman

I've just started using Postman to test an API I am integrating to.

I have the following error that keeps showing up

> Invalid CORS request

Note the following:

1. The API uses Bearer token authentication(OAuth2). I have this
   working without a problem.
2. I do get the bearer token successfully, assign it to an Environment variable and then attempt to use it for the RESTful operations.
3. The problem is in the subsequent RESTful operation that uses the token.
4. When I use an old token (through a POST operation), it rightfully
   tells me that it is expired and not authorized.
5. When I then generate a new one and try to run the restful call, it gives me that `Invalid CORS request` error.
6. **Using cURL, I have no issues. But I am frustrated by Postman**.

What I have found so far:

1. [Using postman with Http POST requests](https://devexchange.thirdlight.com/viewtopic.php?id=94) ***- I don't get the part in bold***

> Just in case anybody else has this same problem, here is how to solve
>   it. Go to https://www.getpostman.com/docs/capture in your chrome
>   browser.  Click on interceptor extension and then choose add to
>   chrome.  Once it is added there is a new icon top right of both the
>   browser and postman that looks like a traffic light.  In postman click
>   this and it turns green. **Then add a header to every request going to**
>   **third light.  Every header consists of the header name and a value.** 
>   **Start typing over the header name and a list of allowed http headers**
>   **comes up.  Choose "Origin".  In the cell for value simply type the**
>   **full URL of your server.  (Do not forget the 'http://' or 'https://')**.

2. [What is the expected response to an invalid CORS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064273) - **Best explanation I have seen so far on CORS errors.**

The other material speaks about `Access-Control-Allow-Method header`, `preflight requests`

... and there is an illustrative Apache Tomcat flowchart of the CORS flow.

[image]

Answer (score 27):

Here's the answer you found again:

> Just in case anybody else has this same problem, here is how to solve it. Go to https://www.getpostman.com/docs/capture in your chrome browser. Click on interceptor extension and then choose add to chrome. Once it is added there is a new icon top right of both the browser and postman that looks like a traffic light. In postman click this and it turns green.

... With the bit in bold translated:

> Then add a header to your request.  The header Key should be "Origin" and the header Value should be the full URL of your server (Do not forget the `http://` or `https://`).

Note that Chrome/Postman won't allow you to add a Header with a Key of Origin without the Interceptor plugin.

Also note that at least on my system the Interceptor icon no longer looks like a traffic light.

Answer (score 10):

If your back-end service side code checks for origin of the request (just to avoid CORS attack) you may face this issues when testing your Rest API through postman.

**How to Resolve this .?**

You need to install a Chrome plugin called **Postman Interceptor** (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en).

After successfully installing this plugin , in you Postman client you can see small icon called Postman Interceptor , you need to toggle it to turn it on.

Now you can add a Request header as below

RequestHeader Key "Origin"
RequestHeader Value **"your application base URL"**

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s96fe.png)

Now you should be able to over come CORS issues you are facing
Cheers !!

Answer (score 3):

Just avoid using browser/chrome postman plugin. Use the desktop application instead!

Answer (score 2):

Seems our server is seeing from a Postman manual HTTP POST that the orgin is invalid b/c its coming from Postman as "chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop"

Not sure why or how to resolve on client/Postman side.  Seems our server is correclty rejecting it as is though and issuing a 403.

Comment: facing the same issue and postman interceptor isn't working. is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

Value of "Origin" header set in Postman request should be allowed in API backend. For example, using Spring Boot for API should have next:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${cors.allowedOrigins}")
    private String allowedOrigins;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*");
    }

}
```

where allowedOrigins is set using `application.properties` property `cors.allowedOrigins` having comma separated list of allowed origins, eg:

```
cors.allowedOrings=http://localhost:8080,http://example.com
```

and set 'Origin' value in Postman to any url from `cors.allowedOrigins`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when testing my APIs on the postman. Even after meticulously configuring my cors.  So I used Insomnia instead of Postman and it works fine. I guess sometimes postman is the problem as it needs some extra effort.

Answer (score -2):

You can try new version of PostMan. To me it works after upgraded postman version from 5.5.5 to 7.36.5

Comment: You should add from which version you upgraded to which. This answer may be useless to someone in the future if a future version causes the same issue or if they are already on the latest version but still have the problem.