# How to reject CORS preflight request?

Tags: cors, backend

There are many questions about how to 'fix' errors with CORS, but not much about how to correctly reject a CORS request that as a server-side developer I want to reject and cause to fail.

So what is the correct way to reject CORS?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561839/how-should-server-respond-to-cors-requests-with-origins-it-wishes-to-deny

Answer (score 0):

As the many questions about trying to fix CORS suggests, largely you can response with anything that doesnt correctly match, e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` that doesnt match the request `Origin` or anything else.

But given the wide variety of ways CORS can match or not, the best way would be to give no CORS headers.

To quote from whatwg

> In case a server does not wish to participate in the CORS protocol, its HTTP response to the CORS or CORS-preflight request must not include any of the above headers. The server is encouraged to use the 403 status in such HTTP responses.

It's worth noting that the documentation doesn't mention a required `2XX` status code, so don't rely on an e.g. `403` to reject CORS.

[1] https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS