# S3 CORS policy for public bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

It seems to be easy, but I don't know what I am missing.
I have a public bucket with a js script that I fetch from my web site. I noticed that I don't send `Origin` header to S3, it is not required and everything works without any CORS configurations.

What's more, even after I manually added Origin header to that GET call and explicitly disallowed GET and my domain via:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://www.nonexistingdomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I can still get the content. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after a conversation with Quentin, I think I understand where I am misinterpreting how CORS should work.
In Java world, it's a very common practice to actually reject requests when Origin doesn't match. Here is another thread where it's [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015118/what-is-the-expected-response-to-an-invalid-cors-request/14064273#14064273). 
If we take Spring as an example(which is de-facto standard in Java world), here is what happens when CORS filter is added:

```
    String allowOrigin = checkOrigin(config, requestOrigin);
    ...

    if (allowOrigin == null) {
        logger.debug("Reject: '" + requestOrigin + "' origin is not allowed");
        rejectRequest(response);
        return false;
    }
```

where:

```
/**
 * Invoked when one of the CORS checks failed.
 */
protected void rejectRequest(ServerHttpResponse response) {
    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/DefaultCorsProcessor.java#L103).

But to my surprise, it is not such a common practice with other stacks and server-side technologies. Another common approach would be to send whatever CORS configuration they have to the browser and leave the decision to it.

**S3 is even more tricky: it only sends CORS response headers when the bucket CORS rules match the CORS-enabled request(a request qith Origin header). Otherwise, there would be no CORS response headers.**

Answer (score 2):

The Same Origin Policy is a feature enforced by **browsers** which prevents JavaScript running on one website from reading data from a different website. (This stops random websites using JavaScript to use your browser to skip past your corporate firewall and access your intranet or read your GMail with your cookies).

CORS lets a website **relax** the Same Origin Policy to allow other websites to read data from it that way.

CORS is not authentication/authorisation. Your public bucket is **public**.

You aren't using JavaScript to **read data** from your bucket, you are loading the JS directly from the bucket.

Comment: I do use js to load the other js. It's a way to make sure that my tracking code is only loaded once.

Comment: I didn't say CORS has anything to do with auth.

Comment: While CORS is enforced by browser it's first and foremost a mechanism to protect a server. And the server should react accordingly when the request with Origin header(or pre-flight) has arrived.

Comment: @yuranos87 — No. It is not designed to protect the server at all. The same origin policy is designed to stop Evil Site using Victim's Browser to read data from Other Site that is supposed to be a secret kept between Other Site and the Victim. CORS is designed to allow Other Site to let Trusted Site access that secret data (or to say that the data isn't secret at all).

Comment: Well, that is what I meant. Maybe "protecting the server" is not the most accurate way to put it, but it's about protecting data that is on the server. "Read data from Other Site" - is about the data on the server after all.

Comment: In any case, it doesn't answer my original question, unfortunately.

Comment: And loading JS is not reading data. Nor is loading an image with `<img>` or a stylesheet with `<link>`.

Comment: It does answer your qestion. You can get the content because you are loading JS, not reading data.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting. How is it different? It's still an HTTP GET. If there is a way that browser can distinguish whether it's <script> loading, it would make sense. But I also tried accessing that script via Postman HTTP GET with Origin set to a different domain and it's accessible.

Comment: The browser can distinguish between `<script>` and `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` before **they are all inside the browser**! That's like being surprised you can tell the difference between picking up an apple with your hand and with your teeth. Postman is not a browser and doesn't enforce the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Yes, but the server(AWS S3 in this case) shouldn't let the request be processed. If I create a web app with, say, java and I don't add a CORS filter in it, it won't return a regular response in result to a request with a mismatching Origin. The presence of Origin header in the request is key to enable CORS mechanism.

Comment: As I have said several times already: The Same Origin Policy is enforced by the **browser**, not the server.

Comment: You **could** write a web service which checked for the Origin header and did something with it beyond comparing it to a whitelist of allowed origins and then echoing its value back in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header if it was on the list, but that would be a **highly atypical** thing to do. Certainly, the CORS configuration settings for S3 don't do that. I've never seen *anything* that does that. The CORS specification doesn't suggest you do that. If you did do that, you wouldn't be using CORS, but would be using the Origin header for something entirely different.

Comment: Why "beyond"? And what do you suggest a server should do if Origin value is not on the list? In my opinion the server should return 403.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191797/discussion-between-yuranos87-and-quentin).

Comment: "beyond" because that is the limit of what the spec recommends. If the Origin value is not on the list, then it should simply not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header but otherwise, behave normally. Special casing and 403ing would be a level of extra complexity for no gain.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the problem and try to understand the fundamentals of CORS.

#### What is Cross-Origin Request & CORS?

> Cross-Origin Request: A request for a resource (like
>   an image or a font) outside of the origin is known as a cross-origin
>   request.

CORS is helpful when you are requesting for a protected resource from another origin.

> Cross-Origin Request Sharing: A request for a **protected** resource (like an image or a font or an XHR request) outside of the origin is known as a cross-origin request.

#### Why do we need CORS when the resources can be protected by using authentication/authorization tokens?

CORS is the first line of defense. When both the client (e.g., browsers) and servers are CORS-aware, clients will allow only requests from the specific origins to the servers as per instructed by the servers.

By default, browsers are supposed to implement same-origin policy security mechanism as per the guidelines on building the browser. Almost all the modern browser implement same-origin policy that instructs the browsers to allow requests to the servers if the origin is the same.

Same-origin policy is a security mechanism of a browser, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). It is because of this feature of browsers, the browser blocks all the request when the designation origin and the source origin are different. (Servers are not even aware that this is happening, Wow!)

For simpler use cases, when the assets(js, CSS, images, fonts), XHR resources are accessible with the same origin, there is no need to worry about CORS.

If assets are hosted on another origin or XHR resource are hosted on servers with a different domain that the source then browsers will not deny the request to cross-origin by default. Only with appropriate CORS request and response headers, browsers are allowed to make cross-origin requests.

Let's look at the request and response headers.

[**Request headers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#The_HTTP_request_headers)

- Origin
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Access-Control-Request-Headers

[**Response headers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers)

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
- Access-Control-Expose-Headers
- Access-Control-Max-Age
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods Access-Control-Allow-Headers

For setting up CORS the `Origin`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers are needed. Browsers will automatically add `Origin` header to every request, so a developer needs to configure only `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

For protecting access to resources only from specific domains, S3 provides an option to configure CORS rules. If the value of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is `*` all the cross-origin requests are allowed, or else define a comma-separated list of domains.

There are a couple of things you need to be aware of when using CORS.

- It's the first level of defense to a protected resource and not the ultimate defense.
- You still need to implement appropriate authentication & authorization for the resource to perform CRUD operations on the server.
- Implementing Same Origin Policy is a guideline for building the browser and are not mandatory.
- CORS headers are useful only when clients accept the headers. Only modern browsers accept CORS headers. If you are not using browsers to make the resource request, then CROS do not apply.
- If you type the link in the address bar of the browser, the CORS rules are not applied to because the browser does not send the `Origin` header to the server. The `Origin` header is sent by the browser only on the subsequent resource request (stylesheets, js files, fonts) and XHR requests by the origin.

  - If you access the resource file by directly typing the link in the address bar, the browser does not send `Origin` header to that request.

Also, if you want to restrict GET access use S3 pre-signed URL on a private bucket.

Answer (score 0):

And to complete @Quentin answer and @yuranos questions, you can easily spoof the Origin http header in your own implementation of a browser, for exemple using webview2 / edge. And simply set it to what the targeted server address is.
So as @Quentin said:

> the same origin policy is a feature enforced by browsers and is not
> designed to protect the server at all

.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).