# Silence javascript errors in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, cors

Suppose I'm doing a CORS request but I don't always know it works for various reasons. A request like:

```
$.ajax('http://a-website.com:8888');
```

When it fails, the browser shows an error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://a-website.com:8888`. Origin `http://another-website.com` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

How can I intercept it and avoid it showing up in the page console as an error?

Comment: Why do you want to silence the error log? That's what it's made for. Maybe, you could try `window.onerror`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to trap CORS errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors)

Comment: I want to silence it as it's somewhat an expected behavior in the scenario I'm building, and it's not something the user should be alerted when it happens. Anyway I'm referring to Chrome. Firefox silently fails.

Comment: But only developers or those that are interested would have the developer console open!

Answer (score 0):

You can put your ajax call in a try catch

```
try{
   $.ajax('http://a-website.com:8888');
}
catch(e){
   //your catching logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's being printed in console, it means something is doing that.

In my projects, I use top print a JS variable in HTML Document, and use a function for printing in console. That function also allows to provide a title for the log and prints data's type.

In that function I verify that variable, if it's false I just return without printing anything. This way I can easily shutdown any log application-wide.

I suggest you to take a look where this console.log() is, and delete it, or ask its author to allow disabling it.

Comment: This kind of error is outputted by the browser itself, not a particular script I have access to.