# Why CORS gives different response at different content-types

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, content-type

When making a call to the server of the third party domain without a request content type, I get a CORS error and no response. But when making a call with a content type text/plain (which is the the true content-type of the response) then I get a response but with a CORS error so I am unable to parse that to the dom. The question is why is the response coming the second time and not the first time. Both are still a CORS error. How can I parse the error the second time since I am getting a response from the server?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_info.txt', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', undefined);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            console.log('Test');
        };
        xhr.send(null);
        var contentXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
        contentXHR.open('GET', 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_info.txt', true);
        contentXHR.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
        contentXHR.onload = function () {
            console.log('Test request header');
        };
        contentXHR.send(null);
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
            Check console and network tab
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I agree to your point @jaromanda-x that the network tab lies many times. I have noticed it. Its basically a warning I am aware of. But if you look the the response the first XHR request has no response from server but the second XHR request has a response but not parsed from the browser. What I want to know is - can I parse the response coming the second time and if yes how. OR if I cannot parse the response then how can I parse the console warning of CORS error. I need to do either one. I dont want to run the browser in insecure mode nor do I want to create an chrome/firefox/edge app here

Comment: Cool. That definitely was a miss. Can I not parse the response then how can I parse the console warning of CORS error using JS?

Comment: I was expecting no status code as well. But its giving status 200 OK. Thats where my async code is going haywire

Comment: Can you check the code again. Its actually giving me status 200. Loadend is triggered

Comment: Loadend event is being triggered with status 200. `var contentXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
        contentXHR.open('GET', 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_info.txt', true);
        contentXHR.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
        contentXHR.onloadend = function () {
            console.log('Test request header');
        };
        contentXHR.send(null);`

Comment: Yes, check the images

Comment: No it doesnt show in jsfiddle as well as plunkr. They have their own parsers. I donot want to hack that minified intercepted code. But for a native browser above is the response/behaviour

Comment: I did not understand what you said. Did you mean its not the behaviour seen? Can you run it in your personal server and not jsbin/plunkr?

Comment: Yeah try that with local or external server rather than jsbin/plunkr parser. You will trigger loadend, error events with status 200 that makes error handling and parsing difficult.

Comment: :-P check this out. The error was replicated same time by Mike. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929313/jsonp-request-returning-json-syntax-error

Comment: Anyways, is there a way I can parse the cors warning by any chance? or can I parse the response by any chance? I need the response access or the cors warning access.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way I can parse the response or the warning? Status 200 is creating issues for me here.

Comment: Ah thats not good that you are unable to replicate. Even I cannot debug an error if I cannot replicate. I think I am stuck. The issue is I will have to write a duplicate function to catch status 200 either in loadend or error function for cors request. Meanwhile, I was trying to hook the console.log into an error stack to try parse the cors error but i was unable to do it. Open a Nodejs/expressjs server or PHP server or Apache httpd; server the html file and make a request. You should be able to replicate it. I am on Win10.xxx/chrome 55.0.2883

Comment: Dont try onload. I am unable to capture it myself. try onloadend or error. Its caught with status code 200 and not status 0. dont use online js playgrounds you will not be able to hack it right. They have their own parsers.

Comment: Alternatively I can try using just events as an identifier but thats not the right way but a workaround

Comment: Ah I think you answered my question. Let me check jsbin and plunkr. They seems to be using a lib like xdomain https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain

Comment: I get no status code set in the response in dev tools in jsfiddle. In the jsfiddle's created dom based console its 0

Comment: `The XMLHttpRequest.status property returns the numerical status code of the response of the XMLHttpRequest. status will be an unsigned short. Before the request is complete, the value of status will be 0. It is worth noting that browsers report a status of 0 in case of XMLHttpRequest errors too. The status codes returned are the standard HTTP status codes. For example, status 200 denotes a successful request. If the server response doesn't explicitly specify a status code, XMLHttpRequest.status will assume the default value of 200.`

Comment: status 0. Is this set in the browser after the request?

Comment: `xhr error 0 contentXHR error 0`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status

Comment: My issue remains. The question is why is the response coming the second time and not the first time (my question). Both are still a CORS error. How do I differentiate both of the above. Is there a way I can differentiate both. Status 0 does not do that.

Comment: Because, as you were told 4 hours ago, the first request you are not seeing a response from a `GET` request, you are seeing the response from an `OPTIONS` request - use firefox, it tells you both in console and network tabs that the first request is `OPTIONS` - and the fact that you can see the response in the console is **irrelevant**. Due to CORS, that response will **never** get to the javascript xhr response

Comment: ok cool. these precisely answered my question.

Comment: the answer has been sitting below for **6 hours** - it was also in a comment I long since removed shortly after you asked the question!! And the reason I've been removing the comments is because you've been **ignoring them**

Comment: it actually did not. The status 0 did. I was trying status 200 in loadend `Its actually giving me status 200. Loadend is triggered` Thanks.

Comment: loadend??? oh hell!!! I didn't even notice you were typing loadend!!! damn I'm an idiot

Comment: No not you. I am one. I did not even do a alert check on status. ah..

Comment: ok, loadend is giving me a status of 0 as well in firefox

Comment: Yeah same here. Cool... thanks.  I think I will be able to work across my functions here.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't specify `Content-type`, XHR executes a `CORS preflight request`. Note that your request is `OPTIONS`, and not `GET`. That's why you don't get any response from the network tab.

According to [CORS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests):

> A header is said to be a **simple header** if the header field name is an
>   ASCII case-insensitive match for Accept, Accept-Language, or
>   Content-Language or if it is an ASCII case-insensitive match for
>   Content-Type and the header field value media type (excluding
>   parameters) is an ASCII case-insensitive match for
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.
>
> (...)
>
> It gets slightly more complicated if the resource author wants to be
>   able to handle cross-origin requests using methods **other than simple
>   methods**. In that case the author needs to reply to a **preflight request**
>   that uses the OPTIONS method and then needs to handle the actual
>   request that uses the desired method (DELETE in this example) and give
>   an appropriate response.

So, in summary, if your Content-Type is different than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`, XHR will trigger the preflight (send a `OPTIONS` http verb).

Comment: Ah that was a big miss from my end. Can I parse/capture the console CORS error from the Javascript code in a normal secure mode settings browser?

Comment: @Gary you cannot access/parse this message. You can set `contentXHR.onerror` callback, but it will trigger as a normal error occurs (including CORS protection). You can check theese questions: [How to Detect Cross Origin (CORS) Error vs. Other Types of Errors for XMLHttpRequest() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325314/how-to-detect-cross-origin-cors-error-vs-other-types-of-errors-for-xmlhttpreq) and [Is it possible to trap CORS errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors), maybe can help you.

Comment: Cool thanks. I think the links are helpful. This might be what I was looking for.