# Running go server on localhost: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes

Tags: javascript, http, cors

I know that this question has been asked many times, but none of the solutions are working out for me.

I'm serving a webpage with a go server.

```
mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../highlight_webpage")))
```

This server is running on port 8080. I have another endpoint I am trying to access, namely:

```
mux.HandleFunc("/get_articles", getNewsArticles)
```

On my webpage, I then try to run an XMLHTTPRequest:

```
var POSTS_URL= 'http://localhost:8080/get_articles';
var STATUS_OK = 200
PostModel.loadAll = function(callback) {
    var postRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()

    postRequest.addEventListener('load', function() {
      if (postRequest.status === STATUS_OK) {
        var posts = JSON.parse(postRequest.responseText)
        callback(null, posts)
      } else {
        callback(postRequest.responseText)
      }
    })
    console.log("loading the function")
    postRequest.open('GET', POSTS_URL + '?user_id=' +  'mchang')
    postRequest.send()
};
```

I then get the error that: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. when I run http://localhost:8080/

My Go Server allows cross-site access. I am confused because: 
1. I don't think I am doing cross site access since these are all on localhost. 
2. I am using a http request to do this request.

Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Detect Cross Origin (CORS) Error vs. Other Types of Errors for XMLHttpRequest() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325314/how-to-detect-cross-origin-cors-error-vs-other-types-of-errors-for-xmlhttpreq)

Comment: So, the page containing the code is loaded using `http://localhost:8080/` and you're trying to GET from same origin? You're definitely loading the page using http, right? Have you tried Firefox?

Comment: `My Go Server allows cross-site access` - what CORS headers do you send?

Comment: From what I read, there's a *long standing* bug in Chrome when a port is specified with `localhost` - so, it would be interesting to se if it works if you change your "go server" to use port 80, and remove all `:port` stuff from your code