# Identify fetch error as due to CORS issue

Tags: javascript, error-handling, cors, fetch

I'd like to tell if a resource load has failed due to a CORS error, as I'd like to then use a proxy I've set up on my server. I don't want to use my proxy unless absolutely necessary as quite a lot of extra data will be piped through it.

When I do:

```
fetch("https://some-resource-somewhere-that-a-user-has-provided")
    .then(response => {
      // do stuff with the response
    }).catch((e) => {
       // e === Error("TypeError: Failed to fetch")
    });
```

The error is pretty unhelpful (on chrome at least), but there is big red text in the console giving me the information I need!

How do I tell that

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

is a CORS issue, or some other load problem?

Comment: Have you tried something other than a browser, e.g. Postman, to check that the api works as planned?

Comment: see if this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325314/how-to-detect-cross-origin-cors-error-vs-other-types-of-errors-for-xmlhttpreq

Comment: If the browser is blocking your frontend code from accessing the response for reasons related to CORS, then the browser will log a specific error message in the devtools console that explicitly mentions CORS. So if you don’t seen any error message in the devtools console that mentions CORS, then the reason the code is failing is not related to CORS. Instead it’s a network issue, or an SSL issue, or something.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - please actually read the whole question!

Comment: @Darran Sweeney - yes the endpoints work, just don't have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * response header.

Comment: @Narkhede - thanks, this certainly help with direction, no obvious answer tho.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?
 
`try {
  await fetch('http://stackoverflow.com');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}`

Comment: @Narkhede Tushar - this just gives the same error but with async functions.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with below solution:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onerror = function () {
  if (this.status === undefined || this.status === 0) {
    console.log('error due to CORS issue');
  } else {
    console.log("** An error occurred during the transaction", this);
  }

};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://stackoverflow.com", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: fantastic, though can you explain why, and how you know it will always be a CORs issue?

Comment: In CORS, the enforcement point is the client. so my assumption is there won't be any status available.