# Catching async exceptions from CORS request

Tags: javascript, exception, amazon-s3, cors

I'm letting users upload files to an amazon s3 bucket by granting them signed URL's from a web server via an ajax call.

Every once and a while the request will go haywire and give me a 403 (As to why I don't know). I have try catch blocks wrapped around my xhr request, but this exception doesn't get caught.

Looks something like this

> https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/hB22C1m9KAll477LWIGx42fTuK4htm?AWSAccess…JKQ6DXF43A&Expires=1385394844&Signature=/OKomeLHinfcDvm30O/9b+9edkw=
>   403 (Forbidden)
>   bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/hB22C1m9KQ6DXF4TuK4htm?AWSAccessKeyId=AK…Q62CNKF3PC3QLA&Expires=1385394844&Signature=/OKomeLHkplfcDvm30O/9b+9edkw=:1

So 2 questions.

- Is it possible to catch an async exceptions from a CORS requests?
- Why would I be getting a forbidden? (Only thing I can think of is if the URL expired, but I have a long timeout, and it gets used the moment it's received from the server via AJAX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async exceptions on CORS requests sent via xhr can be caught by checking the onreadystatechange event.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = ƒ(e) {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        try {
          console.log('good');
        }
        catch (error) {
          alert("There has been an error");
          console.log(error);
          return false;
        }
        callback();
      }
      else if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status !== 200) {
         console.log('There has been an error');
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is an error making the CORS request, the XMLHttpRequest's `onError` handler will fire. You won't have any useful information as to why the error occurred, but you will know there is an error. See the following question for more details: [Is it possible to trap CORS errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors)

As to why you are getting a forbidden error, that is tough to know. Your assessment of urls expiring could be possible, especially if every now and then a request takes longer than expected.