# jQuery CORS and 404

Tags: jquery, cors, asp.net-web-api2

My webserver returns 404 for a request since I've not implemented the controller action yet. The request was a preflight request (OPTIONS) and I can see that 404 is returned in Chrome dev tools.

What suprise me is that jQuery returns status code 0 instead. Can I get the original error code in some way?

[image]

The HTTP response is generated by ASP.NET WebApi. Should it be considered as a bug that the CORS header is not included in the error page? Or do jQuery not handle the error code correctly?

Comment: You've hit the same origin policy, so it's not really a 404, it never got that far.

Comment: As a solution: always response with the code 200 for OPTIONS requests.

Comment: @adeneo: 404 is returned. Is it a violation of the CORS specification. If so, please link to the specification and the part that says that only 200 should be returned.

Comment: I didn't say a 200 should be returned, you can return any statuscode you want, but even if you're seeing the 404 in the console it never reaches the jQuery ajax callback as the request was stopped by the same origin policy, that's why you're not getting a statuscode or any headers.

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [reported this as a bug](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1951) in ASP.NET WebApi.

The response from the ASP.NET team is:

> Global filters run after action selection, hence we never get to the point where the filter is running.
>
> This request changes the basic behavior of CORS filters and hence it will be a breaking change to take this ask.
>
> However since are going to reimplement CORS in ASP.NET vNext, I would like to ask you to open this issue (although CORS is not implemented yet) for tracking on www.github.com/aspnet/mvc

If you want this fixed, [vote on my new issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/565) at github.