# Why is AngularJS error message empty on error handling?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, promise

I am using the AngularJS code to make a request to the server. On success it works fine, but when I redirect the request to some other domain provoking the CORS problem intentionally, error handling function is invoked but errorData is empty. In Chrome when i debug I can see that error function is hit and also I get message "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." in the console but I can not access it from code. How to log this error?

```
RemoteService.doRequestPromise().then(
function(resp) {
    LEService.logIt(resp);
    if (status != 200) {
        LEService.error(resp);
    }
},
function(errorData) {
    LEService.error({ 'err': errorData });
}).finally(function() {
    usSpinnerService.stop('spin1');
});
```

Comment: I think this is because the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` does not receive any information when Chrome preempts the request with a CORS error.

Comment: It seems the following post answers (negatively, I'm afraid) your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what angular gives you for a [failed CORS request](http://plnkr.co/edit/RkecCkQMvfKt0xzU6rM9?p=preview):

```
{
  "data": null,
  "status": 0,
  "config": {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "url": "https://some.site/thing",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    }
  },
  "statusText": ""
}
```

Nothing about CORS but you have a status of `0` and an empty `statusText`. There probably aren't many other scenarios where you'd receive a status of `0`, but it's something worth putting more research into if you absolutely need to be sure that this is a CORS error.