# Catch error of authorized WebAPI 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api2, authorize-attribute

Cannot catch error using jQuery... Any clue?

**JS**

```
var url = "http://localhost:57371/api/Apps/";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "get",    
    success: function (response) {
        alert("second success");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

**ASP.NET WEBAPI 2**

```
[Authorize]
    public class AppsController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/Apps/")]
        public IEnumerable<App> Get()
        {
            var r = new List<App>();

            using (var ctx = new REDEntities())
            {
                if (ctx.Apps.Any())
                    r.AddRange(ctx.Apps.ToList());
            }

            return r.ToList();
        }
}
```

**Console**

> jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 GET http://localhost:57371/api/Apps/ 401
>   (Unauthorized) send @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 ajax @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9143
>   (anonymous) @ Index:96 dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5201 elemData.handle
>   @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5009 Index:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:57371/api/Apps/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://localhost:57166' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 401.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to enable `CORS` on web api , because you are trying to access the api from a different website.

Comment: @MathewJibin Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Its rather simple,[See this guide](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) for details. Essentially it boils down to calling `config.EnableCors()` after installing `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` package.

Comment: the question is about catching the error instead, isn't it?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Yes, I need to display `alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);` the error properly and that's it.

Comment: @Dimi, [you cannot access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors) responseText of a request which result in CORS error.