# Catching "Failed to load resource" when using the Fetch API

Tags: javascript, error-handling, cors, fetch-api

I'm trying to catch a bunch of errors related to the same origin policy when using the Fetch API but without any success:

```
window.onerror = (message, file, line, col, error) => console.log(error)
window.addEventListener('error', (error) => console.log(error))

try {
    fetch('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/').catch(e => {
        console.log('Caugth error:')
        console.log(e)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
    })
}
catch (e) {
    console.log('try-catch')
    console.log(e)
}
```

The errors I want to catch only appear in the web console:

[image: error messages]

<s>See code example here: https://github.com/nyg/fetch-error-test</s>

How can I catch these errors to provide an on-screen message?

**EDIT**: The fetch's catch block is actually executed.

```js
fetch('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(pre)
    .catch(e => {
        pre(`Caugth error: ${e.message}`)
    })

function pre(text) {
    var pre = document.createElement('pre')
    document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', pre)
    pre.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', text)
}
```

```css
pre {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember, you can not `catch` browser driven exceptions in your typical `try->catch` or a `catch chain` inside of `fetch`.

CORS exceptions are thrown with intent, to have the user browsing the site, know of such abnormalities if you may call them that, and to protect any leak of possible secure information on the called api/server

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors)
Of a previous SO discussion on whether you could catch these errors with an exception handler

If the request throws an error that can be part of the response , like a status error and such, then you may catch it and show a custom message

Comment: Looks like you're right :). Thanks for the link, I had failed to find this discussion... However, even though I can't catch these errors, the fetch's catch block is in fact executed (I probably had some issue with my code). The error message is just `Type error` on Safari, `Failed to fetch` on Chrome and `NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` on Firefox. I've edited my answer with a code snippet.