# Error: "TypeError: Failed to fetch" while making a GETrequest to a third-party API using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

After so many research and spending hours on this issue, I am about to ask that
I am making a Get Call to a third party Infutor API. And I am using fetch API in my ReactJS Project. First It started giving me CORS error, then i added `mode: 'no-cors'` in option, then it started giving me `Error: "TypeError: Failed to fetch"`.

Following is my exact code:

```
const response = await fetch(`${INFUTOR_API_URL}?${infutorParams}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors', 
    credentials: 'include',
  })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

I found existing answers like

- [Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch and Cors error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754388/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-and-cors-error)
- [Catching "Failed to load resource" when using the Fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512248/catching-failed-to-load-resource-when-using-the-fetch-api)
- And other related answers

After searching related answers on web I have also tried to add `credentials: 'include'` in it, then i have also tried to make get request with `mode: 'cors'` and tried so many solutions, but had no success. it just don't get data from GET request.

I get response on POSTMAN even on copy pasting url with parameters in new chrome tab gives response back.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the request with the chrome developers tool? I think the "network" tab could be useful in this case.

Comment: @FrancescoManicardi Yeah i have also tried to figure out this issue from network tab, it become red, says failed to load response. and no additional information.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like CORS headers are not properly set up in the server side: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

If that's set up properly, you dont need the `no-cors` flag at all.
It that's not set up properly, you wont be able to access to content anyway.

Comment: when you use Postman and query the endpoint, do you see an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response? what is the value?

Do you see any other fishy `Acces-Control-` headers that could restrict your usecase?

Comment: in postman i don't get any Access-Contorl header in response, what exactly that means?

Comment: that means exactly that the server doesnt support requests coming from other origins in the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

You can either ask the API owner to provide these headers for you, or you have to use a proxy to query the resources you'd like (which is a shady solution).

Comment: @ShahjahanKhokar if this answers your question, please select my post as an answer

Comment: Actually No, I was having no clue to do it from reactjs frontend side, so i moved this functionality in my own Node API and perform a call in Node via fetch api, and that works fine, i was unable to figure out why that is not working from reactJs i was writing a same code for fetching from this third party api.  `const res = await fetch(URL);`

Comment: @ShahjahanKhokar please do your reading on CORS, so you understand why it behaves different from the browser