# Capture jQuery $.ajax error (or Browser console error) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-console

Here is a basic jQuery $ajax function, where I purposely call a fake endpoint;

```
const URL_RESTEndpoint = "http://localhost/api/MyEndpointIntentionalNotExist"
$.ajax(
{
    url: URL_RESTEndpoint,
    method: "PATCH",
    //etc...     
})
.done( (data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
    //do stuff with data...
})
.fail( (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
    //do stuff with error params...
})
.always ( function (data_xhr, textStatus) {
    console.log(textStatus);
}
```

When the above code runs, on the Browser console (of Chrome) it prints out a long error string:

```
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/api/MyEndpointIntentionalNotExist' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource."
```

Ok. Fine. But I'd like to somehow capture the above console error string within my js code, is it possible?

I've inspected all of the .$ajax objects or parameters; the best it can do is show the literal string  "error" as the error. Seriously ?!

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to the commentators and links, apparently it is a security hole to capture CORS errors in JS.
No answers required, I voted to close the question, but it may help someone in future.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors and https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/838

Comment: Have a look at: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/