# Ajax detect "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We are using third party API on our code to get data.

```
$.ajax({
  url: API,
  success: function(html, textStatus, xhr){
    //IF OKAY
  },
  error: function(html, textStatus, xhr){
    console.log( "!!!!!!!!! ERROR !!!!!!!!!!!!" );
    console.log( "----", html );
    console.log( "----", xhr.status );
  },
});
```

How can detect on error if the error is

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your arguments for `error` are incorrect, First one is the jQXHR object and status will be `0`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to definitively access this type of error in browsers for security reasons. Please see this similar thread [Is it possible to trap CORS errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844643/is-it-possible-to-trap-cors-errors)